# Interactive compilation mode in emacs ? (what if compiler asks a question)

Tags: emacs

I am looking for either a hack to regular compilation mode, or suggestion on how to create new mode.
What i want to achieve, is to 'compile' my code - but the compilator sometimes asks certain questions on the terminal (yes/no, etc etc).
Afaik, regular compilation mode can't direct my keyboard input and feed the subprocess with it.
Is that possible ?

Thanks

Comment: Does the compiler in question have an option to run in batch mode, i.e., without asking questions?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

`C-u M-x compile RET` is all you need.

This is, in fact, documented: typing `C-h f compile RET` shows

```
Additionally, with universal prefix arg, compilation buffer will be in comint mode, i.e. interactive.
```

Comment: If calling the `compile` function directly, add a second parameter to make the compile buffer interactive: `(compile "my command" t)`.

Answer (score 3):

If you know all of the answers in advance, you might be able to get away with something as easy as:

```
(setq compile-command "(echo yes; echo no; echo yes) | (old compile command)")
```

Answer (score 1):

I have switched from using the compile mode to using an async shell command. Here's the lisp:

`(defun run-it ()
  "Run it on the current file."
  (interactive)
  (save-buffer)
  (shell-command
   (format "my_command %s &"
       (shell-quote-argument (buffer-name)))))
(global-set-key "\C-ct" 'run-it)`

It saves the buffer first. The `&` makes it actually interactive so I can enter text in the buffer and the command will get that input. An added benefit is that it colors the command output on the fly, which my compile buffer was not doing.

Answer (score 0):

It seems the only way to achieve what i want, is to use comint package.
I'm going to override regular compile mode, to determine (upon file type) whether compiler will or won't ask any questions - if not, use regular compile, otherwise use my custom comint-integrated buffer.

Answer (score 0):

I might have found another solution in the case where you can't or don't want to use the universal prefix argument. You can set you local variable's `compile-command` second argument to `t` and run `recompile` instead of `compile`. This allows to have the information stored as a local variable permanently.